# How to type custom hook useStateWithCallback React TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm having problem to type the following custom React `hook`, I'm new to TypeScript and this is causing some confusion.

```
const useStateCallback = (initialState: any) => {
  const [state, setState] = useReducer<Reducer<any, any>>((state, newState) => ({ ...state, ...newState }), initialState)
  const cbRef = useRef(null)

  const setStateCallback = (state, cb) => {
    cbRef.current = cb
    setState(state)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cbRef.current) {
      cbRef.current(state)
      cbRef.current = null
    }
  }, [state])

  return [state, setStateCallback]
}
```

Should I use `any` here, if so how do I use `any` properly?
Since this is universal function and can be used anywhere, how do I type it correctly?

I added some of my tryings right inside my example, and, as you can see I stop, because from my side of view it'll ends up with nothing but `any` types.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: @DennisVash I added my tryings

Comment: What is the purpose of this hook? How would you use it that's different from `useState`? And what do you use the callback for? (React already re-renders if state changes, so you typically dont need to trigger anything manually on state change)

Comment: @Alex Wayne I use it to ensure that state is actually changed, and I can proceed. This way I can track it in external functions that does't use React

Comment: So you can proceed with what? Because that's exactly what an effect with a dependency does This `useEffect(someFunction, [somethingFromState])` would run `someFunction` automatically anytime that `somethingFromState` has finished saving a change.

Comment: @Alex Wayne What the exact point of your question? This hook does what it suppose to, and it works fine as is. My question is focused on how to type this hook, so it can be used typescipt-similar to `useState` inside React component.

Comment: You're right. I apologize. Re-reading this today and my tone was not what you deserved! I'll provide at least a partial answer shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you'll need to make this `useStateCallback` accept a generic parameter that represents your state. You're going to use that parameter a lot. We'll call that `S` for state.

```
function useStateCallback<S>(initialState: S) { ... }
```

Next up is the reducer. It looks like you want just a single action that accepts a [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt) of `S` that gets merged into the state.  So for the two generic parameters in `Reducer` we use `S` for the state and `Partial<S>` for the action.

```
const [state, setState] = useReducer<Reducer<S, Partial<S>>>(
  (state, newState) => ({ ...state, ...newState }),
  // state is implicitly typed as: S
  // newState is implicitly typed as: Partial<S>

  initialState
)
```

Or you could type the arguments of the reducer function, and those types would be inferred, which looks a bit cleaner, IMHO.

```
const [state, setState] = useReducer(
  (state: S, newState: Partial<S>) => ({ ...state, ...newState }),
  initialState
)
```

For creating the ref, we need to give it a type of the callback function, unioned with `null` since it may not always contain a value:

```
const cbRef = useRef<((state: S) => void) | null>(null)
```

for `setStateCallback`, we need to accept a `Partial<S>` to merge with the full state, and a callback that has the full state as it's only argument:

```
function setStateCallback(state: Partial<S>, cb: (state: S) => void) {
  cbRef.current = cb
  setState(state)
}
```

Your effect should be good as is.

Last thing to do would be to change your return to:

```
return [state, setStateCallback] as const
```

This is required because typescript sees this as an array by default, but you want it to be a tuple. Instead of an array of `(S | Callback)[]` you want it be a tuple with exactly two elements of type `[S, Callback]`. Appending `as const` to the array tells typescript treat the array as a constant and lock those types into the proper positions.

Putting all that together, you get:

```
import React, { useReducer, useRef, useEffect, Reducer } from 'react'

function useStateCallback<S>(initialState: S) {
  const [state, setState] = useReducer<Reducer<S, Partial<S>>>(
    (state, newState) => ({ ...state, ...newState }),
    initialState
  )
  const cbRef = useRef<((state: S) => void) | null>(null)

  function setStateCallback(state: Partial<S>, cb: (state: S) => void) {
    cbRef.current = cb
    setState(state)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cbRef.current) {
      cbRef.current(state)
      cbRef.current = null
    }
  }, [state])

  return [state, setStateCallback] as const
}

// Type safe usage
function Component() {
  const [state, setStateCallback] = useStateCallback({ foo: 'bar' })

  console.log(state.foo)

  setStateCallback({ foo: 'baz' }, newState => {
    console.log(newState.foo)
  })

  return <div>{state.foo}</div>
}
```

[Playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzksgCb5pJTZElIBmNxAovfUhtmRVXAL5x6UCCDgByKKgxiAUDPr4AdhmARFBYgGUYKGEgDCKADZGARugDWAHk0A+ABTBFwGMGPbdSAFxxNASlwZODgguDQ1QngAbUjPbGIYDz0AXTgAXg06ckooe1Dg+1i9H01sRSQAdyTvOAAFFFg3IxtbALTbOHs8ADpeoqRsXu7yqp09fj9MfLgnFybq0L9Q8MVIsNNkenTMzat7QrGa-3SOgDcIYFIAgB84RXwTB3uTJdCFZVc1OATqwxNzNAWA6eHz1RrGFrYNCmHzA4q+NpnC5XQLBYLQzbdND4KCSRTwDLQ6Y-Q5wpBLYJ8OTBWisdgYfaI1Fo4BbewYhhYnF4mABHDTdEbTnY3FIfFkilowWYkU87bPIzTKmU7AxQ7JV7BSQwHHqNVxb5IRKHP5mSypFCEMIRGAyKkyAD0DrgABUAJ5gJDfFDsDQoADmSHkShUX30Ikg5XFfOWNrg+r08SNv2MZsBqQytBT-0sXUEEAgPjE5igYgm1OtqwgRiQ3SMEH9ZO69ALmsNxs8poBQLwLcL4nMAC8y3wypVqidmeiItXa-XGyNqs3W6E+G3tbq4FZSMBTrYcP1lxA+FYHTu93agA)

Comment: Thank you, it helps me a lot! Allthrough TS playground is not asking for typing the function's return, my ESLint settings does. If I just apply [S, Callback] it will not work, because... what is the "Callback" and it's type (from you answer above)?

Comment: `Callback` was just a placeholder, but it represents `type Callback = (state: S) => void`. You shouldn't have to type the return value of the function as long as you return the tuple at the end with `as const`.

Comment: @ Alex Wayne Thank you for the clarification