# Pass setState as a parameter Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Consider the following:

```
// external file

export const someFunction = setState => {
    setState({ value: "some new string" })
} 

// component's file

import { someFunction } from "pathToFile"

interface TState {
    value: string
}

const [state, setState] = useState<TState>({ value: "some string" })

useEffect(() => {
   someFunction(setState)
}, [])
```

Is it possible to achieve that `someFunction` will accept **only this particular** `setState` function as а parameter? If so, how it could be done?

To be clear, I want:

```
someFunction(setState) // pass
someFunction(setAnotherState) // fail
someFunction(anotherFunctions) // fail
someFunction() // fail
someFunction(0) // fail
someFunction(true) // fail
someFunction({}) // fail
```

Comment: By 'fail' do you mean you want typescript to throw a type error while transpiling?

Comment: @Swayam Yes, this is what I meant

Comment: If I understood you correctly useState is typed for accepting an object with "value" key which value is a string. Thats all

Comment: If, for example, I allow the second option with `setAnotherState` - still not possible?

Comment: I was wrong, bela53's answer is correct and beautifully solves this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you are asking for a [nominal type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal):

```
type NominalSetState = React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<TState>> &
  { readonly __brand_setState__: unique symbol }

const someFunction = (setState: NominalSetState) => {
    setState({ value: "some new string" })
}

function useNominalState(init: TState) {
    return useState<TState>(init) as [TState, NominalSetState]
}

const [state, setState] = useNominalState({ value: "some string" })
const [anotherState, setAnotherState] = useState<TState>({ value: "some string" })
```

Now, tests behave as desired:

```
someFunction(setState) // pass
someFunction(setAnotherState) // fail
someFunction() // fail
someFunction(0) // fail
someFunction(true) // fail
someFunction({}) // fail
someFunction((...arg: any[]) => any) // fail
```

[Live code example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgKIBmZSG2RSAyjCjEnAL5xlQQhwBEUqDLwBQwmAE8wLAHLdgAOxQAbOkhgMmLALyJBMAHQARYITBM0ACwA8ydAdXrGzAIIZgEeVYAqG5gD4-OAAyYTwBFAATDyVxOAB9OIAjKBR5CLjiR00EgC4CeWAAR3wWQnEQRIglNlE0D0J4Qm4kADF8eTcPOB0ACkzfJDzZEAVlBwGASm7A4Tg5uH6nJB68ADdlErzeJpAWeSQAdwWYKAUAc142CeFWUQVmKDJ0Fh8l3Fn59aVN49P5M5uojI7U68gIxGGoxUSx6CmAMDyr00UxwHzmAhg%20CgYNoA28Az8sIKMCmKEIcAA2kjmNhIYoVGoBgBdQHCOryBqUhqabCLTRM7rgpB0sYwtYbQZ8HalE7nS6sa7szkU1IQGAWJBQAa8tTOeRqjVapYCnS4pb4paE8XfSXbZq-OVXUTCaVtDowdzyPqMpZTAD0frgZkIhBdzTdoO9MD1Bs1kzgAY4KGASjDuwjHo8PX9gaeKbTrRBma9AAYc0n866i56eicSuW86mq%206azgFQnc8mm%20Hq1mevoBygoGc8qlxBSmVMtIExw2u0A)

Comment: I don't see a reason, why nominal types shouldn't work there (though having only skimmed through the linked post). In the end a branded type is just an intersection with a type as unique as possible. You can adjust `NominalSetState` to your needs.

Comment: I still have trouble figuring how to modify `NominalSetState`, [in case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62902367/how-to-type-custom-hook-usestatewithcallback-react-typescript) when I'm passing an additional function after the `InitialState`. How should I modify `NominalSetState` for this type of use?

Comment: Please post a [minimal playground code example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) that exactly reproduces your issue/error.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your goal by implementing the callback methods.

Example:

```
this.readStudentFile(anyFile, this.callback);

callback(isPass) {
 this.setState({ isPass: isPass });
}

readStudentFile(file: File, callback) {
 if(file) {
   callback(true);
 } else callback(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a very specific parameter type to `someFunction`, which will give you the same pass/fails that you want.

Only allowing one particular object isn't what Typescript is really for - you are meant to guard by only allowing some interfaces, and anything with that same interface will be allowed.